# filter columns and merge rows

Tags: ms-access, filtering

I have a data set in access. I want to use the query table or write a query in access software.

```
Customer Name + ID               Salesperson Number             Ship To State
32 ONTAR INC ** X6458                M  
32 ONTAR INC ** X6458                G                         ON
2-Z  INC ** C5228                    H                         FL
2-Z  INC ** C5228                    A                         FL
4SITE ESTATE ** F4685                H                         CA
A & A CONCRETE INC ** A6785          N                         NJ
```

I want to have a unique Customer name+ID and in the second column and third column, I want to have merge information like the table below.

```
Customer Name + ID               Salesperson Number             Ship To State
32 ONTAR INC ** X6458                M,G                           ON
2-Z INC ** C5228                     H,A                           FL
4SITE ESTATE ** F4685                  H                           CA
A & A CONCRETE INC ** A6785            N                           NJ
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a field named 'Customer Name + ID' do you?  That's completely wrong.  Also, why would you want to do this?  This violates normal form and reduces data integrity.  If you really insist on doing this kind of thing, I suppose you can do it.  Again, I would recommend against it.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]

SQL:

SELECT tblData.ID, Conc("Field1","ID",[ID],"tblData") AS Field1, Conc("Field2","ID",[ID],"tblData") AS Field2
FROM tblData
GROUP BY tblData.ID;

Or, you can use a UDF to do the job for you.

```
Option Compare Database

Function ConcatenateName( _
  LastName As Variant, _
  FirstName As Variant, _
  MiddleName As Variant, _
  Title As Variant _
) As String

ConcatenateName = LastName & _
    (", " + FirstName) & _
    (" " + MiddleName) & _
    (", " + Title)

End Function
```

[image]

SQL:

SELECT Table1.*, ConcatenateName([Last],[First],[Middle],[Title]) AS Concatenation
FROM Table1;

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have an "undefined Conc function" error. I attached the picture.

Comment: So, you are all set now?!  It definitely works.  If you don't get it on the first try, just fiddle with it.  You will figure it out!